# A translation for the Bulgarian word "колбас", less specific than "sausage"

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

In Bulgarian we have the word "колбас" (kolbas) which means roughly "cooked meat, almost always with additives, usually ground, usually wrapped in an intestine or in something else".

English terms that denote kinds of "kolbas" include:

- Sausage
- Salami
- Bacon
- Ham

But online dictionaries translate "kolbas" to simply "sausage", which is really only one *kind* of "kolbas".

Note: I found the cognate "Kiełbasa" which has been borrowed into English from Polish. But it means just a type of sausage.

Comment: "Cold cuts" covers pretty much all precooked, processed meat products except what I would call breakfast sausages. Sausages may or may not be sold precooked. There is also *charcuterie*, but I don't know how widely or well that term is known.

Comment: Is that related to [**Kabanos** Sausage?](http://www.melaniecooks.com/kabanos-sausage/1252/) Which I've always assumed came from Eastern Europe rather than the Med - they're well enough known to me in SE UK, but definitely not *English*.

Comment: If you go looking for them in a US supermarket they'll often be under a sign saying "deli meats."

Comment: I’m a bit confused. Bacon does not fit the description you give (at least not raw).

Comment: I'd go with "processed meats", but I don't have references or enough justification to make it an answer.

Answer (score 7):

According to [this definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/charcuterie) *charcuterie*  covers most of the prepared meat products listed in the question. It is originally a French term but has been adopted into English so seems like a good translation of *kolbas*

Comment: Calling ham and bacon _charcuterie_ seems quite odd, though. And I suspect there are several kinds of cold cuts which would count as charcuterie, but probably not as _kolbasa_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That's the trouble with translation generally though, there are very few exact translations between any two languages. It's why _charcuterie_ has been adopted into English from French and _delicatessen_ from German because English didn't have a good word for either. Also the linked definition says that charcuterie means cold cooked meat which covers ham and bacon as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 3):

***Sausage*** *is* the generic term covering raw, ground meat and spices in a casing of some sort. (For example, typical Italian sausage, or breakfast links.)

It also refers to those types which are preserved by smoking and drying, like, salamis, summer sausages and pepperoni.

"Sausage" can also be used to describe the myriad German "wursts". (US)

Comment: Doesn’t work for ham and bacon, though (even if bacon doesn’t actually fit the description given by the asker, ham does). The main difference would be that the Bulgarian term only implies _usually_ ground and _usually_ encased, whereas both are an integral part of the definition of _sausage_.